# Django uploading and importing a file

Tags: python, django

I have a Django app that is basically a web front end on a database.

Every now and then, users upload files containing perhaps 1000s of records. These records will need to be parsed out of the file, processed, and used to create new records or update existing records in the database. I'm just wondering what is the better approach for processing the uploaded file:

- in the view (while the user waits - I guess this could be a up to 5 minues) ?
- save the uploaded file and have some background cron job call a custom admin command to process it? This seems the most sensible to me.
- or perhaps another method I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Celery seems to be pretty hot these days too, you should definitely look into this:

### https://github.com/ask/django-celery

### http://celeryproject.org/

[image]

Send an email when done, or have the front end poll for results every X seconds after submission. *"Are we there yet?" "Are we there yet?"*

---

I'd like to know too a simple, safe way to start a thread that writes to the db.

Comment: yeah your'e right it's too ripe for mistakes. I'll remove that.

Comment: I thought kicking threads off in Django wan't a good idea? I've heard good things about celery, but thought it may be a bit overkill for my needs - this will probably only happen a few times a week if that.

Comment: maybe some experts can chime in on how to best start a thread and potentially concurrently read/write to the db. You could rephrase your question to that!

Comment: Is using a cron job to run a custom admin command to process the file not a good idea? If so, why not?